# how to catch msal login failure event in 2.x or no cache authority error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal-angular

I am using 2.x MSAL Angular library and facing issue while logging in after user has changed his password with the error : no cache authority found. I want to catch this event and redirect user to login screen but unable to find any way. Please find the error details below :

[no authority cache error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqTNY.png)

[msal failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8snd3.png)

I tried with

'''

```
 this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
      .pipe(
        filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE || msg.eventType === EventType.HANDLE_REDIRECT_END),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
        debugger;
        // Add your auth error handling logic here
      });


   this.authService.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe({
      next: (result) =>
      {
        console.log(result)
      } ,
      error: (error) =>  {
       
        console.log(error)
      } ,
    });
'''
```

but none of them event is fired.

Library versions:
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.14.1",